# I cannot see the time in the menu bar

Tags: unity, indicator

Since I re-installed Ubuntu 13.04, I can't see the time next to the volume control. I installed Unity Tweak but the show time box is already checked. What can I do?

Comment: What locale are you using (just in case it is a language pack bug)? And, try opening `dconf-editor` then navigate to `com > canonical > indicator > datetime` and see if the options there are correct. (To install `dconf-editor` run: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.) If possible please add the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep indicator.datetime` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Dash (top left, ubuntu logo), then type "time" and it should be the only option. Set it from there.
Peace!

Comment: There are no options